# All of the modification times for my files have been shifted by 1 hour, how can I restore them en masse?

Tags: files, rsync, timezone

I have two copies of my data, one of which seems to have shifted the modification times by an hour inexplicably (well, we did have a daylight switch recently). I typically use rsync to keep the two copies in sync, and now I have to use the much slower checksum option to handle this sync job. Is there any way I can use rsync or another tool to restore the modification times? Will using rsync with `-t` and `-c` do that? I have run a dry run and it seems to be modifying the directories, so I am assuming it is modifying the times. I do not want to mess it up further, though.

Comment: I'm unclear on which of the copies (rsync source or destination) got changed. If it's the destination, why not let the regular rsync run take care of things? Also, I'm assuming you've checked the system time on the destination and source, if you're copying to a remote system. Maybe the DST switch isn't on one of them?

Comment: The source and destination are local. I can let rsync take care of it, but without the checksum it will rewrite like 40 GB to the microSD card and that could take a long time. And the checksums take a while too. But I guess that seems to be my only option.

Comment: Checksums are not useful on local copies.  You have to read the entire file to generate the checksum.  Run  with `-i` and see if the first character of the status for the files is a "." or a ">".

Comment: If you have a backup of the files with correct timestamps, you could either restore from that backup, or create an [`mtree`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mtree) specification from the backup, and apply the specification to the live files.